# R shiny: different behaviours of observeEvent and eventReactive

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, handsontable, rhandsontable

The shiny app below displays an editable table built with `rhandsontable()`.

**Question**: Can you explain me why `"ping"` is printed to the console whenever an edit is made to the data table while `"pong"` is never printed.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  rhandsontable::rHandsontableOutput(
    outputId = "data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
  
  output$data <- rhandsontable::renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable::rhandsontable(
      selectCallback = TRUE,
      data = data)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$data$changes$changes, {
    print("ping")
  })
  
  edits <- eventReactive(input$data$changes$changes, {
    print("pong")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `edits()` isn't called thereafter, so `shiny` thinks you don't need it, hence no reason to do any work on it, you need to add where it should go or what you want to do with it:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    rhandsontable::rHandsontableOutput(
        outputId = "data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    data <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
    
    output$data <- rhandsontable::renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable::rhandsontable(
            selectCallback = TRUE,
            data = data)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$data$changes$changes, {
        print("ping")
    })
    
    edits <- eventReactive(input$data$changes$changes, {
        print("pong")
    })
    
    observe({
        edits()
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```